# Navbar & Div arrangement on window resize (Bootstrap Responsive)

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

This is a navbar following twitter bootstrap form - it will drop the elements and eventually replace them with the mobile convenient collapsible button.

http://www.bootply.com/109p4a4Mk3

But when it goes into mobile/collapsed view - the nav items arrangement is very crummy - what's the best way to specify organization (float, margin's, width etc.) that is only applicable on collapsed view. (For example links, about and contact, could fit into one row rather than 3).

Answer (score 0):

you can define in a custom css to negate bootstrap default css something like:

```
/* when navbar start collapsing */    
@media (min-width: 768px){
 .nav>li {display:inline;}
}
```